# Bootstrap popover error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Im trying to undersatand bootstrap popovers. I decided to add a button inside of it. But it doesnt work as expected since it reads the content after closing it. Im using the screenreader NVDA to read the page (I want it to be accessible)

https://jsfiddle.net/devmyrrie/qv5vp9qc/

```
<button  type="button" class='fa fa-question-circle claim-icon' data-placement='above'>Open Popover</button>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" class="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">
   <div>
      Awesome example
   </div>
   <button type="button" id="fh-tooltip-close" class="fh-tooltip-close" aria-label="Close tooltip"> x
   </button>
</div>
```

And the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var claimIconState = false;

    $('.claim-icon').popover({
      html: true,
      content: function () {
        return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
      }
    })


    $(".claim-icon").on('shown.bs.popover', function (e) {

      //When a close tooltip button  is clicked we need to  bring focus back to the button who opened the tooltip
      $(".popover-content").find('.fh-tooltip-close').on('click', function () {

        //Focus to button that  opend it
        $('.claim-icon').focus();
        $('.claim-icon').popover("hide");
      });

    });
    $('.claim-icon').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
      $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false;
      $('.fh-tooltip').attr("aria-hidden", "false");
    });

  });
```

When I click the close button, it reads the content of the now disappeared popover. Any idea why?